# Is there an easy way to get the implied xml:lang value for an element?

Tags: xml, xpath, multilingual

According the the W3C specification:

> The language specified by xml:lang applies to the element where it is specified (including the values of its attributes), and to all elements in its content unless overridden with another instance of xml:lang.

If we look at the following example,

```
<foo xml:lang="en">
    <bar>Some words!</bar>
    <bar xml:lang="fr">Different words!</bar>
    <bar xml:lang="fr">
        <buzz xml:lang="de">Other words!</bar>
        <buzz >Other words!</bar>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

`foo` and the first `bar` element are `en`, the second and third `bar` elements are "fr", while the first `buzz` is "de", while the second is "fr".

Is there an easy way to use XPath to quickly determine what the inherited `@xml:lang` value for an element would be if present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes!

The XPath just below can be
used to find the correct value of an `xml:lang` attribute from the context of a given element.

```
ancestor-or-self::*[attribute::xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang
```

The decribed pieces at each stage are underlined using
carets, and broken down this:

1. Follows the tree back to the root, through all ancestors, and returns only
   those that have an `@xml:lang` attribute.

   ```
   ancestor-or-self::*[attribute::xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. This list is returned in order going away the element we are searching from,
   so we grab the first (or closest element).

   ```
   ancestor-or-self::*[attribute::xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang
                                           ^^^
   ```
3. Having the nearest element that has an xml:lang set, we than just return the
   value of its `@xml:lang` attribute.

   ```
   ancestor-or-self::*[attribute::xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
   ```