# How to use inherited xml:lang with Python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, multilingual

According to the xml spec the language attribute `xml:lang` is inherited to children. But can I use that in any Python tools?

I found a related XPath question: [Is there an easy way to get the implied xml:lang value for an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-implied-xmllang-value-for-an-element) That answer has a complex XPath:

```xml
ancestor-or-self::*[attribute::xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang
```

But I cannot figure out how I can use that in ElementTree or lxml. (Beautiful Soup does not support XPath at all.)

We have a collection of multi-language documents like this, and would like to collect and count `<important>`-elements in different languages:

```xml
import lxml.etree as ET
# import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''
<project>
<doc xml:lang="la">
  <title>Lorem <important>ipsum</important></title>
  dolor <important>sit</important> amet.
</doc>
<doc xml:lang="sv">
  <title xml:lang="la">Consectetur <important>adipiscing</important> elit</title>
  Viterligit warj allom them som <important>thetta breff</important> see.
</doc>
</project>'''

root = ET.fromstring(data)

importants = {'la': [], 'sv': []}
for important in root.iter('important'):
    lang = important.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang']
    importants[lang].append(important.text)
print(importants)
```

If I put the `xml:lang`-attributes straight in the `important`-tags, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lxml [supports XPath 1.0](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath). Replace the `lang` expression in the question with the following:

```py
lang = important.xpath("ancestor-or-self::*[@xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang")[0]
```

Resulting output:

```
{'la': ['ipsum', 'sit', 'adipiscing'], 'sv': ['thetta breff']}
```